# lot of warnings after installing facebook SDK on my iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

i am trying to install facebook SDK on my iOS app in order to make social login using facebook account. but after installing through cocoapods, it gives me a lot of warning message. I am using Xcode 9.2. here is the code on my podfile when installing using cocoapods

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'facebook login firebase' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for facebook login firebase

pod 'Bolts'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

end
```

and here is the screenshot of the warning
[image]
https://ibb.co/kx5fCR 
(here is the link in case the image doesn't appear)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started
i am in the step 4 of that documentation, but the warnings show up. so what went wrong in here? do i miss something?

Comment: You can ignore these warning. Warning are may be due to version mismatch of system and framework. Framework works properly, dont wry.

Answer (score 9):

Here is your complete `Podfile` section for installing the Facebook Swift SDK as static libraries and without warnings:

```
  pod 'Bolts', :modular_headers => true, :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FacebookCore', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FacebookLogin', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FacebookShare', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', :modular_headers => true, :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', :modular_headers => true, :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', :modular_headers => true, :inhibit_warnings => true
```

If you don't want to bother with individual inhibitions, add at the top of your `Podfile`

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Also, if you're using frameworks with

```
use_frameworks!
```

then you can skip the need to specify modular headers for the dependencies and simply

```
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
```

*answer current as of Xcode 9.4 / FacebookLogin 0.3.1 / FBSDKLoginKit 4.35.0 / Cocoapods 1.5.3*

Comment: This should be marked as a correct answer. It cleared all unwanted warnings for me...Thak you Alex C.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of warnings are kind of the norm when using third-party code. Either fix this stuff upstream in Bolts or live with it since it can't really hurt your product.